# How to keep file and folder names the same as on Windows when extracting on Linux

Tags: zip, unzip

I have problems compressing and extracting a folder containing Chinese characters (ISO-8859-1 encoded) between windows and Linux

I have a folder named  Ã–ÃÃ”Â­Â¶Ã¾Ã‡Ã¸ (and many files have similar names in inside) but after extracting it at Linux it was changed to something like Ãƒâ€“ÃƒÂÃƒâ€Ã‚Â­Ã‚Â¶ÃƒÂ¾Ãƒâ€¡ÃƒÂ¸.
How can I extract it to Linux with the same name as Windows?

(I tried using WinSCP to upload this file to Linux in binary mode (uncompressed), everything works fine)

Comment: Did you try `tar` command line tool?

Comment: You may use a zip utility that uses UTF-8, such as the free [Bandizip for Windows](https://www.bandisoft.com/bandizip/).

Comment: Yes, I have used almost all the extracting software: rar, tar, 7z and zip

Comment: I mean on the zipping side. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)